# Conditional formating in sharepoint 2016

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, conditional-formatting, sharepoint-2016

I am new in SharePoint and I try to build conditional formating on row level on my current list. I have SharePoint 2016.

I need rows where date () is less then a month away from current date to become RED. Something like a reminder that that date will expire soon.

Here is my view/list from SharePoint Designer    :

```
<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"    Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=16.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document"  %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="ApplicationPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:ListProperty Property="TitleOrFolder" runat="server"/> - 
    <SharePoint:ListProperty Property="CurrentViewTitle" runat="server"/></asp:Content>
<asp:Content contentplaceholderid="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:RssLink runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageImage" runat="server"><SharePoint:ViewIcon Width="145" Height="54" runat="server"/></asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderLeftActions" runat="server">
<SharePoint:RecentChangesMenu runat="server" id="RecentChanges"/>
<SharePoint:ModifySettingsLink runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderBodyLeftBorder" runat="server">
    <div height="100%" class="ms-pagemargin"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=40" width='6' height='1' alt="" data-accessibility-nocheck="true"/></div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
        <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="None" ID="Main" Title="loc:Main" orientation="Horizontal"><ZoneTemplate>
<WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server" ViewFlag="" ViewSelectorFetchAsync="False" InplaceSearchEnabled="True" ServerRender="False" ClientRender="True" InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" WebId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" IsClientRender="False" GhostedXslLink="main.xsl" ViewGuid="{F7212227-9019-4F54-B800-545BE358B599}" EnableOriginalValue="False" DisplayName="AllItems" ViewContentTypeId="" Default="TRUE" ListName="{6C30C684-C0E7-4F05-9888-D0E4DB589E40}" ListId="6c30c684-c0e7-4f05-9888-d0e4db589e40" PageType="PAGE_DEFAULTVIEW" PageSize="-1" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" DataSourceID="" ShowWithSampleData="False" AsyncRefresh="False" ManualRefresh="False" AutoRefresh="False" AutoRefreshInterval="60" Title="EBM_Service_account" FrameType="Default" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" Description="Lista EBM servisnih naloga" IsIncluded="True" ZoneID="Main" PartOrder="2" FrameState="Normal" AllowRemove="True" AllowZoneChange="True" AllowMinimize="True" AllowConnect="True" AllowEdit="True" AllowHide="True" IsVisible="True" TitleUrl="/support/IT_infrastruktura/Lists/EBM_Service_account" DetailLink="/support/IT_infrastruktura/Lists/EBM_Service_account" HelpLink="" HelpMode="Modeless" Dir="Default" PartImageSmall="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." PartImageLarge="" IsIncludedFilter="" ExportControlledProperties="False" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ID="g_f7212227_9019_4f54_b800_545be358b599" ExportMode="NonSensitiveData" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{F7212227-9019-4F54-B800-545BE358B599}" __AllowXSLTEditing="true" __designer:CustomXsl="fldtypes_Ratings.xsl" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""><ParameterBindings>

<ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortdir" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
            <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortfield" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
            <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_startposition" Location="Postback" DefaultValue=""/>
            <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_firstrow" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
            <ParameterBinding Name="OpenMenuKeyAccessible" Location="Resource(wss,OpenMenuKeyAccessible)" />
            <ParameterBinding Name="open_menu" Location="Resource(wss,open_menu)" />
            <ParameterBinding Name="select_deselect_all" Location="Resource(wss,select_deselect_all)" />
            <ParameterBinding Name="idPresEnabled" Location="Resource(wss,idPresEnabled)" /><ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" /><ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" /></ParameterBindings>
            
            
<DataFields>
</DataFields>
<XmlDefinition>
<View Name="{F7212227-9019-4F54-B800-545BE358B599}" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" Type="HTML" DisplayName="AllItems" Url="/support/IT_infrastruktura/Lists/EBM_Service_account/AllItems1.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/generic.png?rev=40" ><Query/>
<ViewFields>
<FieldRef Name="Datum_x0020_kreiranja"/>
<FieldRef Name="Domain"/>
<FieldRef Name="Title"/>
<FieldRef Name="d1lb"/>
</ViewFields>
<RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit><Aggregations Value="Off"/><JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
<XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink><Toolbar Type="Standard"/></View></XmlDefinition>
</WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>

</ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageDescription" runat="server">
<SharePoint:ListProperty CssClass="ms-listdescription" Property="Description" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderCalendarNavigator" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:SPCalendarNavigator id="CalendarNavigatorId" runat="server"/>
  <ApplicationPages:CalendarAggregationPanel id="AggregationPanel" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
```

Thanks in advance!

I read lot of material online and I see that this is easy in SP 2010 ans SP online, but not able to find how to do it in SP2016.

Comment: For SharePoint 2016, you can use JSLink/Client side rendering (CSR) for such requirements. For example, check: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/251405/how-to-highlight-a-row-on-active-status/251416